# Save Elements' Locations to local file after dragging & dropping

Tags: javascript, python, html, frontend, streamlit

I was upgrading one of my projects which is a predictor of rebounding odds based on players' locations on the court. Here is the link: http://okc-thunder-rebounds.herokuapp.com/.

I wanted to make it more user-friendly by enabling dragging & dropping. I mean, users are able to place the items that represent the players anywhere in the court panel. Currently, I'm having a hard time importing the final locations of players when they are placed to my model because, previously, I developed with Python and Streamlit while, right now, I am doing it in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I am a newbie to the latter three so I couldn't find a way that is able to transport/import the data to my python codes directly. I guess it is possible to save the data first locally and then I can read them using python afterward.

So in short: how can I manage to record the locations of items (in pixels) as soon as they are placed and if possible, their records are able to be changed when they are moved?

Here is what I have done to make it drag & drop:

```
<html><head><style>
#red_button1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:20px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#def1 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#red_button2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:60px;
  left:20px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#def2 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#red_button3 {
  position: absolute;
  top:110px;
  left:20px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#def3 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#red_button4 {
  position: absolute;
  top:160px;
  left:20px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#def4 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#red_button5 {
  position: absolute;
  top:210px;
  left:20px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#def5 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#blue_button1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:60px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#off1 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; 
}

#blue_button2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:60px;
  left:60px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#off2 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; 
}

#blue_button3 {
  position: absolute;
  top:110px;
  left:60px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#off3 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; 
}

#blue_button4 {
  position: absolute;
  top:160px;
  left:60px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#off4 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; 
}

#blue_button5 {
  position: absolute;
  top:210px;
  left:60px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
}

#off5 {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; 
}

#panel {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-size: contain;
}

#display {
  position: absolute;
  top:500px;
  left:10px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  display:block; 
  width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="panel" style="background-image: url('court.png');">
<div id="red_button1">
    <div id="def1">1</div>
</div>
<div id="red_button2">
    <div id="def2">2</div>
</div>
<div id="red_button3">
    <div id="def3">3</div>
</div>
<div id="red_button4">
    <div id="def4">4</div>
</div>
<div id="red_button5">
    <div id="def5">5</div>
</div>
<div id="blue_button1">
    <div id="off1" style="color:white">1</div>
</div>
<div id="blue_button2">
    <div id="off2" style="color:white">2</div>
</div>
<div id="blue_button3">
    <div id="off3" style="color:white">3</div>
</div>
<div id="blue_button4">
    <div id="off4" style="color:white">4</div>
</div>
&lt;<div id="blue_button5">
    <div id="off5" style="color:white">5</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Show Positions" onclick="SHowDiv()">
<div id="display"></div>
<script>
//Make the DIV elements draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("red_button1"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("red_button2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("red_button3"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("red_button4"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("red_button5"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("blue_button1"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("blue_button2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("blue_button3"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("blue_button4"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("blue_button5"));

//output their final locations
// getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button1"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button2"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button3"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button4"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button5"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button1"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button2"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button3"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button4"));
// getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button5"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

function getOffset(elmnt) {
    return {top: elmnt.style.top, left: elmnt.style.left};
}

String.prototype.trimRight = function(charlist) {
  if (charlist === undefined)
    charlist = "\s";

  return this.replace(new RegExp("[" + charlist + "]+$"), "");
};

function SHowDiv()
{
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button1")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button1")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button2")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button2")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button3")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button3")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button4")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button4")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button5")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("red_button5")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button1")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button1")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button2")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button2")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button3")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button3")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button4")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button4")).left.trimRight("px") + "<br>" + 
  getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button5")).top.trimRight("px") + ", " + getOffset(document.getElementById("blue_button5")).left.trimRight("px");
}

</script>



</body></html>
```

[image]

And here is the code of my original work:

````
import streamlit as st
from joblib import load
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle, Arc
import plotly
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


# draw the half court
def create_half_court(ax=None, three_line='mens', court_color='#dfbb85',
                      lw=3, lines_color='black', lines_alpha=0.5,
                      paint_fill='blue', paint_alpha=0.4,
                      inner_arc=False):
    """
    Version 2020.2.19

    Creates NBA Basketball Half Court
    Dimensions are in feet (Court is 97x50 ft)
    Created by: Rob Mulla / https://github.com/RobMulla

    * Note that this function uses "feet" as the unit of measure.
    * Our data is within this range: -47 <= x <= 47, -25 <= y <= 25.
    * So to plot X/Y positions first convert to feet like this:
    ```
    loc['loc_x_'] = 47 - loc['loc_x_']
    loc['loc_y_'] = 25 - loc['loc_y_']
    ```
    ax: matplotlib axes if None gets current axes using `plt.gca`
    
    three_line: 'mens', 'womens' or 'both' defines 3 point line plotted
    court_color : (hex) Color of the court
    lw : line width
    lines_color : Color of the lines
    lines_alpha : transparency of lines
    paint_fill : Color inside the paint
    paint_alpha : transparency of the "paint"
    inner_arc : paint the dotted inner arc
    """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # Create Pathes for Court Lines
    center_circle = Circle((50 / 2, 94 / 2), 6,
                           linewidth=lw, color=lines_color, lw=lw,
                           fill=False, alpha=lines_alpha)
    hoop = Circle((50 / 2, 5.25), 1.5 / 2,
                  linewidth=lw, color=lines_color, lw=lw,
                  fill=False, alpha=lines_alpha)

    # Paint - 18 Feet 10 inches which converts to 18.833333 feet - gross!
    paint = Rectangle(((50 / 2) - 6, 0), 12, 18.833333,
                      fill=paint_fill, alpha=paint_alpha,
                      lw=lw, edgecolor=None)

    paint_boarder = Rectangle(((50 / 2) - 6, 0), 12, 18.833333,
                              fill=False, alpha=lines_alpha,
                              lw=lw, edgecolor=lines_color)

    arc = Arc((50 / 2, 18.833333), 12, 12, theta1=-
    0, theta2=180, color=lines_color, lw=lw,
              alpha=lines_alpha)

    block1 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) - 6 - 0.666, 7), 0.666, 1,
                       fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                       lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                       facecolor=lines_color)
    block2 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) + 6, 7), 0.666, 1,
                       fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                       lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                       facecolor=lines_color)
    ax.add_patch(block1)
    ax.add_patch(block2)

    l1 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) - 6 - 0.666, 11), 0.666, 0.166,
                   fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                   lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                   facecolor=lines_color)
    l2 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) - 6 - 0.666, 14), 0.666, 0.166,
                   fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                   lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                   facecolor=lines_color)
    l3 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) - 6 - 0.666, 17), 0.666, 0.166,
                   fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                   lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                   facecolor=lines_color)
    ax.add_patch(l1)
    ax.add_patch(l2)
    ax.add_patch(l3)
    l4 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) + 6, 11), 0.666, 0.166,
                   fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                   lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                   facecolor=lines_color)
    l5 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) + 6, 14), 0.666, 0.166,
                   fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                   lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                   facecolor=lines_color)
    l6 = Rectangle(((50 / 2) + 6, 17), 0.666, 0.166,
                   fill=True, alpha=lines_alpha,
                   lw=0, edgecolor=lines_color,
                   facecolor=lines_color)
    ax.add_patch(l4)
    ax.add_patch(l5)
    ax.add_patch(l6)

    # 3 Point Line
    if (three_line == 'mens') | (three_line == 'both'):
        # 22' 1.75" distance to center of hoop
        three_pt = Arc((50 / 2, 6.25), 44.291, 44.291, theta1=12,
                       theta2=168, color=lines_color, lw=lw,
                       alpha=lines_alpha)

        # 4.25 feet max to sideline for mens
        ax.plot((3.34, 3.34), (0, 11.20),
                color=lines_color, lw=lw, alpha=lines_alpha)
        ax.plot((50 - 3.34, 50 - 3.34), (0, 11.20),
                color=lines_color, lw=lw, alpha=lines_alpha)
        ax.add_patch(three_pt)

    if (three_line == 'womens') | (three_line == 'both'):
        # womens 3
        three_pt_w = Arc((50 / 2, 6.25), 20.75 * 2, 20.75 * 2, theta1=5,
                         theta2=175, color=lines_color, lw=lw, alpha=lines_alpha)
        # 4.25 inches max to sideline for mens
        ax.plot((4.25, 4.25), (0, 8), color=lines_color,
                lw=lw, alpha=lines_alpha)
        ax.plot((50 - 4.25, 50 - 4.25), (0, 8.1),
                color=lines_color, lw=lw, alpha=lines_alpha)

        ax.add_patch(three_pt_w)

    # Add Patches
    ax.add_patch(paint)
    ax.add_patch(paint_boarder)
    ax.add_patch(center_circle)
    ax.add_patch(hoop)
    ax.add_patch(arc)

    if inner_arc:
        inner_arc = Arc((50 / 2, 18.833333), 12, 12, theta1=180,
                        theta2=0, color=lines_color, lw=lw,
                        alpha=lines_alpha, ls='--')
        ax.add_patch(inner_arc)

    # Restricted Area Marker
    restricted_area = Arc((50 / 2, 6.25), 8, 8, theta1=0,
                          theta2=180, color=lines_color, lw=lw,
                          alpha=lines_alpha)
    ax.add_patch(restricted_area)

    # Backboard
    ax.plot(((50 / 2) - 3, (50 / 2) + 3), (4, 4),
            color=lines_color, lw=lw * 1.5, alpha=lines_alpha)
    ax.plot((50 / 2, 50 / 2), (4.3, 4), color=lines_color,
            lw=lw, alpha=lines_alpha)

    # Half Court Line
    ax.axhline(94 / 2, color=lines_color, lw=lw, alpha=lines_alpha)

    # Plot Limit
    ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 94 / 2 + 2)
    ax.set_facecolor(court_color)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    return ax


def slider_setting(condition, position):
    x = st.sidebar.slider('Coordinate X for ' + condition + ' Player ' + str(position), min_value=-47., max_value=47.,
                          value=0., step=0.1)
    y = st.sidebar.slider('Coordinate Y for ' + condition + ' Player ' + str(position), min_value=-25., max_value=25.,
                          value=0., step=0.1)
    return x, y


def locate(locations, court):
    off_ = pd.DataFrame({
        'X': [47 - location[0] if location[0] >= 0 else 47 + location[0] for location in locations[:5]],
        'Y': [25 - location[1] for location in locations[:5]]
        })
    def_ = pd.DataFrame({
        'X': [47 - location[0] if location[0] >= 0 else 47 + location[0] for location in locations[5:]],
        'Y': [25 - location[1] for location in locations[5:]]
        })
    off_.plot(x='Y', y='X', style='X', ax=court, alpha=1, label='Offensive players')
    def_.plot(x='Y', y='X', style='X', ax=court, alpha=1, label='Defensive players')
    label_point(off_, court)
    label_point(def_, court)

def label_point(df, ax):
    for i, point in df.iterrows():
        ax.text(point[df.columns[1]]+ .2, point[df.columns[0]], str(int(i+1)), size=20)

def preprocess(locations):
    input = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'AtShot_loc_x_off_player_1': [locations[0][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_off_player_1': [locations[0][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_off_player_2': [locations[1][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_off_player_2': [locations[1][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_off_player_3': [locations[2][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_off_player_3': [locations[2][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_off_player_4': [locations[3][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_off_player_4': [locations[3][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_off_player_5': [locations[4][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_off_player_5': [locations[4][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_def_player_1': [locations[5][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_def_player_1': [locations[5][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_def_player_2': [locations[6][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_def_player_2': [locations[6][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_def_player_3': [locations[7][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_def_player_3': [locations[7][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_def_player_4': [locations[8][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_def_player_4': [locations[8][1]],
            'AtShot_loc_x_def_player_5': [locations[9][0]],
            'AtShot_loc_y_def_player_5': [locations[9][1]]
        }
    )

    input[[col for col in input.columns if '_y_' in col]] = (25 - input[
        [col for col in input.columns if '_y_' in col]]) / (25 - (-25))
    input[[col for col in input.columns if '_x_' in col]] = (47 - input[
        [col for col in input.columns if '_x_' in col]]) / (47 - (-47))
    return input


def stack_bar(offensive_proba, defensive_proba):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing = 0.15)
    probas = ['Offending<br>Team<br>', 'Deffending<br>Team<br>']  # text to show

    # Move common code to a function to reuse multiple times:
    def plot_bar(probas, visible):
        x_list = [offensive_proba, defensive_proba]
        for x, proba in zip(x_list, probas):
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Bar(x=[x * 100],  # just one number value for a bar
                       y=['Probability'],
                       name='Probability',
                       visible=visible,
                       opacity=1,
                       orientation='h',
                       text=(x),
                       textposition='inside',
                       texttemplate=proba + '%{text:.1%}'),
                row=1, col=1)

    plot_bar(probas, True)
    fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
    # Controlling text fontsize with uniformtext
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)  # hide ledend
    # Set axis font:
    fig.update_yaxes(tickfont=dict(size=14))
    st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this is the trained model
    LDA = load('LDA.joblib')
    st.write('''
    # Welcome to Rebound Probability Prediction!
    ''')
    # placeholder
    imageLocation = st.empty()
    fig, court_ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(11, 11.2))
    create_half_court(court_ax,
                           three_line='mens',
                           paint_alpha=0.4,
                           inner_arc=True)
    # plot the half court without scatter
    imageLocation.pyplot(fig)
    st.sidebar.header('Input players\' locations when the ball is shot:')

    locations = []
    for condition in ['Offensive', 'Defensive']:
        for i in range(5):
            x, y = slider_setting(condition, i + 1)
            locations.append((x, y))

    button = st.sidebar.button('Confirm')

    if button:
        # plot the locations of players on the court
        locate(locations, court_ax)
        imageLocation.pyplot(fig)

        # pre-processing
        input = preprocess(locations)

        ## predict
        # individual
        individual_prediction = LDA.predict_proba(input)[0]
        # team
        offensive_proba = sum(individual_prediction[:5])
        defensive_proba = sum(individual_prediction[5:])

        ## data vis
        # individual
        results = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'Players': ['Offensive Player 1', 'Offensive Player 2', 'Offensive Player 3', 'Offensive Player 4',
                            'Offensive Player 5',
                            'Defensive Player 1', 'Defensive Player 2', 'Defensive Player 3', 'Defensive Player 4',
                            'Defensive Player 5'],
                'Probability': individual_prediction
            }

        )
        st.write('## Individual Probability')
        cm = sns.light_palette("orange", as_cmap=True)
        results = results.sort_values(by=['Probability'], ascending=False)
        st.dataframe(results.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm).set_precision(2))

        # team
        st.write('## Team Probability')
        stack_bar(offensive_proba, defensive_proba)

        # celebrate
        st.balloons()
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later change my solution by letting Flask access to the locations directly. It just needs to assign the value to an invisible textarea, so that we can access it when using Flask.

Codes are like following:
HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('main') }}" id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="hidden" class="form-control" style="display: none;" value="" id="hidden"></textarea> 
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="Assign()" align="center">
</form>
<script>
function Assign()
{
  document.getElementById("hidden").value = "some values";
}
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            value_you_want = request.form['hidden']
```